# Predict i out of n dice rolls where each side has an different probability (unfair dice)

Tags: probability

First of all I want to say that I am not a math expert and this question may seem pretty easy. I have the following problem:

Lets say an unfair dices has $k$ faces ($1,...,k$), where each face has a different probability ($p1,...,p_k$). You know have n such dices. How can you calculate the probability of a specific outcome, if you only need to predict $i$ out of the $n$ dices ($i$ is the amount of dices that you need to predict correctly, where $i<n$)? Is there a general formula to calculate the probability of such a scenario?

Example:
An unfair dice can be described as a dice, where the probability of every number is different. Lets say the probabilities are $p_1 = 0.5, p_2 = 0.25, p_3 = 0.14, p_4 = 0.11$ (respectively for the numbers $1,2,3,4$). We now roll 3 such unfair dices. What is the probability that $2$ and $3$ is rolled?

Edit: I changed the problem a bit, so it is more general.

Edit2: I added an example to clarify the problem a bit.

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. You are more likely to get help rather than downvotes and votes to close if you edit the question to show us what you tried and where you are stuck. Can you answer similar questions  if there are just two such dice?

Comment: @EthanBolker thanks, I simplified the question a bit.

Comment: Actually, you make it more general, not simpler. Can you solve the problem when $k=2$ and $n=2$ and $i=1$? There you should be able to write down all the cases, with their probabilities, in terms of $p_1$ and $p_2$. Please use mathjax: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: @EthanBolker thanks, I hope it looks correct now. I am not quite sure. I am looking for a general formula of such a problem, because I need to implement it and it needs to be a bit flexible, where $k,n$ and $i$ can be different.

Comment: Sorry. This is still not clear. I don't know what "predict" means. If you edit the question to show for a particular small worked out example exactly what numerical combinations would count as a successful prediction perhaps someone can help. Maybe I will try, maybe not.

Comment: Done. Hopefully the example clarifies the problem a bit.

Answer (score 1):

I'll do your example. You should be able to generalize.

For each individual die, the probability that you *don't* get a $2$ is $1-p_2$ so the probability that you don't get a $2$ with $3$ dice is $(1-p_2)^3$. The similar computation for not getting a $3$ is $(1-p_3)^3$. That suggests that the probability that you get both is
$$
1 - (1-p_2)^3 - (1-p_3)^3 .
$$
That's not quite right, because you subtracted "neither a $2$ nor a $3$" twice so you have to add that back in once: 
$$
1 - (1-p_2)^3 - (1-p_3)^3  + (1 - p_2 - p_3)^3 .
$$

You should be able to generalize this. The generalization calls for a general [inclusion exclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) argument.

**Warning:** I wrote this up pretty quickly; there may be a mistake somewhere, although I'm sure of the principle. You should check that it makes sense in simple cases: when there's just one die, when there are just two, when the dice have just two faces, when the dice are fair.

Comment: For the specific values of $p_2$ and $p_3$ mentioned, my answer agrees with yours: In R, `p2 = .25;  p3 = .15; 1−(1−p2)^3−(1−p3)^3+(1−p2−p3)^3` returns 0.18. (+1)

Comment: @BruceET Nice to have that confirmation.

Answer (score 0):

As @EthanBolker and others have Commented, it is not exactly clear what
you are asking. Here is my interpretation. Maybe it is close enough
to what you meant to be useful.

On this unfair die, let $P(X = 2) = p_2 = 0.25,\,$ $P(X = 3) = p_3 = 0.15.$
Also let $p_e = 0.6$ be the probability that some other face is seen.

You want the probability of getting at least one 2 and at least one 3.
Denote something other than 2 or 3 as `E`. Then your condition is met
if you get one of these three disjoint patterns `23E`, `223`, or `233`. 
There are six possible orders for
the first pattern, and three for each of the other two.

So the desired probability is 
$$6p_2p_3p_e + 3p_2^2p_3 + 3p_2p_3^2 = 0.18.$$

More generally, probabilities of events with specific numbers
of particular faces over multiple rolls of such a die can be answered
using the 'multinomial distribution'. For example, the probability of
getting exactly two 2's and exactly two 3's in five rolls of such a die
is given by

$${5 \choose 2, 2, 1}p_2^2p_3^2p_e,$$
where ${5 \choose 2, 2, 1} = \frac{5!}{2!\cdot 2! \cdot 1!}$ is a 'multinomial coefficient'. If multinomial distributions are not covered in your text,
perhaps begin by looking at [*Wikipedia*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_distribution).

---

As a check, the following simulation of a million rolls of three such
biased dice gave $0.1806 \pm 0.0008.$

```
s = replicate(10^6, sum(unique(sample(c(0,2,3), 3, rep=T, prob=c(.6,.25,.15)))))
mean(s==5);  2*sd(s==5)/1000 
[1] 0.180617
[1] 0.0007694014
```

The following tally gives approximate probabilities (accurate to about three
places) of: getting neither a 2 or a 3, getting at least one 2 but not a 3, getting one
3 but not a 2, and getting both 2 and 3 at least once, respectively.

```
table(s)/10^6
s
       0        2        3        5  
0.215455 0.398503 0.205425 0.180617
```